# Mod rewrite question

Tags: mod-rewrite

How can I have booth these rules work at the same time with different values on the same page?

Here is my mod rewrite code.

```
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/?)$ /posts.php?aid=$1&css=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/?)$ /posts.php?aid=$1&w=$3 [L]
```

Comment: The left hand side of both rules is exactly the same, so what do you want to happen? The same number to be repeated twice in the query string?

Comment: I want the third number to hold different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't work like that. You'll have to format your url differently so you can make two distinct reg exp.